# Why is React Native 0.22.2 Movies example click handling so slow?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm running the official React Native 0.22.2 "Movies" example on a physical iPad Mini 2.1 running iOS version 9.3.1, not on the simulator.

I selected the Release scheme and added main.jsbundle to run without a server.

When I scroll down the list of movies and it stops, I click on the movie row.  However it takes a second or two to finally respond and open the details page.

Is there some flag or setting I'm missing to get fast performance?

If not, this is a big disappointment.  Everything I read suggested it would be as responsive as a native app.

Also just ran on iPad mini running 9.2.  It has the same lag when trying to click on a movie row.

Here's a video demonstrating the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2D6gMMVbF6k

I want to know if it's a mistake to start a project with React Native.  If the performance is this bad, I'll just stick with Swift.

Comment: Well, a non-native javascript app would probably have a better performance so I think this is a bug either in the app or in react native (resource loading?)

Comment: Well it shouldn't be the app because this is the official React Native "Movies" app example, straight from their github repo.  I would think their example apps would showcase the performance of their framework.  In other words, their samples should be blazing fast!

Comment: I think something is definitely wrong, probably a regression with the movie example specifically. I've not seen delays like that in actual apps.

Comment: I cannot replicate with latest `react-native` master. I'm thinking however this looks a lot like you might have Debug in Chrome feature on, which causes the app scripts to run on your local development machine. Now, if there was a lot of latency between your machine and the device, the event processing might take a long time. Maybe bring up the developer menu by shaking the device and ensure Debug in Chrome and Hot Loading at turned off?

Comment: Note that the Release scheme only disables the developer menu, it doesn't actually change the way the JS is ran (it can still be in debug mode)

Comment: I thought I covered all the options in the docs.   What's the mechanism for turning off debug JS?